# Unity UI Buttons for Making the Character Move Left and Right Don't Work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game for mobile, and I want to use UI Buttons as controllers instead of the keyboard keys that I use to test the game on my laptop.

Here's the code I use for my character:

```
public float moveSpeed;
private float moveVelocity;
public float jumpHeight;
public Transform tagGround;
public float groundCheckRadius;
public LayerMask playerMask;
private bool IsGrounded;
public Animator anim;

void Start ()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    IsGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (tagGround.position, groundCheckRadius, playerMask);
}


void Update()
{
    moveVelocity = 0f;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W) && IsGrounded) {
        Jump ();
    }

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
        Right ();
    }

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
        Left ();
    }

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (moveVelocity, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);

    anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x)); 
    anim.SetBool ("isGrounded", IsGrounded);
    anim.SetBool ("Attacking", false);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.S)) {
        Atk ();
    }

    if (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x > 0)
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
    else if (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x < 0)
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, 1f, 1f);

}
```

I made the proper functions to go with each key press, and they all work just fine. I called those functions with UI Buttons and both `Jump` and `Attack` work just fine, but `Left` and `Right` don't work.

Here are the properties of my Button script:

[image: Button (Script)]

Answer (score 0):

hope it works:

```
public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    btn_pressed = true;
}

public void OnPointerUp (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    btn_pressed = false;
}

if(btn_pressed)
{
    //code
{
```

Comment: make a class for handling ui button pressed. if-statement goes to Update() method.